# traefik v2 ipwhitelisting middleware error

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik

I am having problems configuring ip whitelisting with traefik 2 on Google Kubernetes Engine

This is the middleware yaml

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: ipwhitelist
  namespace: traefik
spec:
  ipWhiteList:
    sourceRange:
      - 199.83.128.0/21
```

And this is my ingress controller

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: traefik-ipwhitelist@kubernetescrd
  name: front-cms
spec:
  rules:
    - host: xxx.aaa.es
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: front-cms
                port:
                  number: 80
```

When I try to load the webpage I get a 404 (without the `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: traefik-ipwhitelist@kubernetescrd`line it works just fine).

On traefik service logs I get the following error

```
time="2022-11-07T09:53:12Z" level=error msg="middleware \"traefik-ipwhitelist@kubernetescrd\" does not exist" entryPointName=websecure routerName=es-prod-front-cms-xxx-cms-aaa-es@kubernetes
```

- Traefik resource and service are on `kube-system` namespace.
- Middleware is on `traefik` namespace
- web ingress controller is on `es-prod` namespace

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Hey, did you solve it? I have the similar issue

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced a similar issue, also it was just me or it need to be recreated but updating the existing ingress was giving me `404`, after recreating worked for me.
In my case, the middleware was in the same `namespace` where I created the ingress.

So I need to reference like `namespace-middlewarename`.

> When you define a middleware in Traefik using annotations in Kubernetes, Traefik automatically append the name in the format namespace-middlewarename. This CR object represents the middleware configuration in Kubernetes.

[image]

It is also worth checking the dashboard for middleware existence, but the `not found` is something from misconfiguration

```
k port-forward pods/traefik-59f79fc9b-4pchp 9000:9000
```

[image]

Here is complete working example, might help someone else

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: ipwhitelist
spec:
  ipWhiteList:
    sourceRange: {{ toYaml .Values.sourceRange | nindent 6 }}
```

ingress

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      meta.helm.sh/release-name: kafka-ui
      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kafka-ui
      traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: kafka-ui-ipwhitelist@kubernetescrd
    generation: 1
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: kafka-ui
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kafka-ui
      app.kubernetes.io/version: v0.5.0
      helm.sh/chart: kafka-ui-0.5.1
    name: kafka-ui
    namespace: kafka-ui
  spec:
    ingressClassName: traefik
    rules:
    - host: kafka-ui.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: kafka-ui
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - kafka-ui.example.com
      secretName: kafka-ui.example.com
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```